# How to fix GCP OCR returning null for bounding poly vertices for text?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vision, google-vision

Google Cloud Platform's OCR returns the bounding box coordinates fine in most cases, but sometimes it returns NULL which is really annoying because I need the bounding box for it to function properly. I have noticed that this happens usually when the text is close to the left/right edge, but I can't find confirmation of this anywhere. Even the documentation here:

https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/vision/v1/java/latest/com/google/api/services/vision/v1/model/Vertex.html#getX--

here says that it just returns `null for none`, but I was wondering if anyone can confirm if this only happens if the box is outside the dimensions of the image, as this would save me a lot of hassle.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vision API uses [Protocol Buffers v3](https://cloud.google.com/apis/design/proto3)

> An unset primitive field has a language-defined default value.

If the X or Y value is unset, it means it is 0.